# How to calculate the expected loss of a credit card transaction?

Tags: probability

I have used an algorithm to calculate the probability of a credit card transaction to be fraudulent. The algorithm outputs a classification (fraud/no fraud) and the probability of each, such that P(fraud) + P(no_fraud) = 1. I want to rank the transactions to be manually reviewed not only by the probability of it being fraudulent, the amount at risk in each transaction.

Currently, I am using (P(no_fraud)*amount)-(P(fraud)*amount) to calculate some sort of net expected profit. My goal is to rank all transactions by the expected loss they may cause to my business. I have considered instead ranking transactions only by P(fraud)*amount, i.e., by expected loss. Do any of these two equations make sense? What would be a better alternative?

Comment: Can you clarify how you earn/lose money? E.g., are you a customer whose revenue is offset by fraudulent charges, or are you a card service which takes a percent commission off each transaction but is on the hook for fraudulent transactions?

Comment: actually, the second describes the situation accurately.